# MySQL: How to order receipt number that contain "new receipt number" and "original receipt number"

Tags: mysql

Table A (Order By Id DESC)

| Id | receipt | og_recept | is_modify |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | XX03-XX04-00000000-B | XX03-XX04-00000000 | 1 |
| 7 | XX05-XX06-00000000 |  | 0 |
| 6 | XX04-XX05-00000000 |  | 0 |
| 5 | XX02-XX03-00000000-B | XX02-XX03-00000000 | 1 |
| 4 | XX03-XX04-00000000 |  | 0 |
| 3 | XX01-XX02-00000000-B | XX01-XX02-00000000 | 1 |
| 2 | XX02-XX03-00000000 |  | 0 |
| 1 | XX01-XX02-00000000 |  | 0 |

Expected Result:

| Id | receipt | og_recept | is_modify | group | group_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XX01-XX02-00000000 |  | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | XX01-XX02-00000000-B | XX01-XX02-00000000 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | XX02-XX03-00000000 |  | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | XX02-XX03-00000000-B | XX02-XX03-00000000 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | XX03-XX04-00000000 |  | 0 | 3 | 1 |
| 8 | XX03-XX04-00000000-B | XX03-XX04-00000000 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 6 | XX04-XX05-00000000 |  | 0 | 4 | 1 |
| 7 | XX05-XX06-00000000 |  | 0 | 5 | 1 |

I want to order `receipt` column where `Id ASC order` and `is_modify=0` (Id 1->2->4->6->7). If it exists `og_receipt & is_modity=1` put that row record under it's related receipt (Id 3,5&8).

`og_receipt` is empty value `''` not null.

(MySQL v5.5.23)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `receipt` gets replicated into `og_recept` so using `coalesce()` conveniently "groups" by `receipt` and then `og_recept` (and/or `is_modify`)  will do the rest.

```
select
*
from table1
order by coalesce(NULLIF(og_recept,''),receipt), receipt


+----+----------------------+--------------------+-----------+
| Id |       receipt        |     og_recept      | is_modify |
+----+----------------------+--------------------+-----------+
|  1 | XX01-XX02-00000000   |                    |         0 |
|  3 | XX01-XX02-00000000-B | XX01-XX02-00000000 |         1 |
|  2 | XX02-XX03-00000000   |                    |         0 |
|  5 | XX02-XX03-00000000-B | XX02-XX03-00000000 |         1 |
|  4 | XX03-XX04-00000000   |                    |         0 |
|  8 | XX03-XX04-00000000-B | XX03-XX04-00000000 |         1 |
|  6 | XX04-XX05-00000000   |                    |         0 |
|  7 | XX05-XX06-00000000   |                    |         0 |
+----+----------------------+--------------------+-----------+
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e0e6e/2

as `og_recept` isn't NULL in the table, but empty strings, use `NULLIF()` to treat it as NULL inside the `COALESCE()`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention og_receipt is empty value not null.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95f360f/1

Comment: modified answer, use NULLIF() on that column inside the COALESCE()